# TensorRT python package incompatibility with python 3.6

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, tensorrt

Installing [TensorRT 4](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-install-guide/index.html#installing) from its tar file is the only available option if you installed [CUDA using the run file](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile).  However, the tar file only includes python TensorRT wheel files for python 2.7 and 3.5.  No python 3.6 wheel file provided.

I cannot force install the python 3.5 wheel file on my python 3.6 system:

```
$ pip install tensorrt-4.0.0.3-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl 
tensorrt-4.0.0.3-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Also, I cannot create a new python 3.5 virtualenv just to use TensorRT.

Is there a way to manually install this package on my python 3.6 platform by manually copying the files?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can rename this file to tensorrt-4.0.0.3-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl and try again.

It works.

Comment: Note here: due to the above renamed issue, there may be import errors, need to find the corresponding file corresponding to the error, and also corresponding to rename it as 36.
For example: import tensorrt as trt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorrt.infer._nv_infer_bindings'
Corresponds to ****/tensorrt/infer/_nv_infer_bindings.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
Renamed it to _nv_infer_bindings.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

Comment: Search 35 on **/tensorrt, change all to 36

Comment: ImportError: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, And I can't find '*3.5*' in the tensorrt package

Comment: The version I originally used was tensorrt-4.0.0.3, and this problem did not occur with direct changes. Now change to tensorrt-4.0.1.6 and it does have this problem. Such change is not a cure.

Answer (score -2):

Please use python version 3.5.5. I had same issue with python version 3.6. Latest version of tensorflow works with python 3.5. If you are using anaconda use conda shell to activate earlier python version.  You can set environment to use earlier version of python.